# Redhat “httpd” can not start anymore. Showing “suEXEC” and “SELinux” notices

Tags: linux, rhel, apache-httpd, selinux

I'm on RHEL `6.5` and Apache `2.2.15`. When I `restart` the `httpd`, I can not start that `httpd` anymore. Showing following things in the `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[Fri Aug 01 18:31:48 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 01 18:32:35 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Fri Aug 01 18:32:35 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 01 18:42:46 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Fri Aug 01 18:42:46 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 01 18:43:15 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Fri Aug 01 18:43:15 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 01 18:43:59 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 01 18:44:12 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Aug 01 18:45:03 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

Actually I have already `disabled` the `SELinux` and rebooted.
What should I do please?

Comment: These aren't errors, they're just notices. You might need to post more of the error log.

Comment: These messages are not revelent to the non-startup of httpd....please provide log information that is more revelent (i.e. not notice level...but error level or above).

Comment: Also, errors that occur before httpd fully starts may not even goto the error log. Try starting the `httpd` process manually to inspect stdout.

Comment: But whenever i try `service httpd start` it failed and a new error lines been added, as like above. **Actually i'm applying the SSL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, I have found the reason. This is totally because of the `SSL CERT` problem. Not really because of above `notices`.

---

**It was nothing to do with above mentioned Messages.**
Therefore please just ignore them.

---

How do I do was that I enabled the Apache Detailed Logs and then that's the real move. It shows what really is happening, by showing the Failure at the loading of mod_ssl module, while starting the Apache. Then I realized it is because of `ssl.conf` (or the respective Vhost file) having the SSL Cert configurations inside.

There I made 2 mistakes. First, I didn't give read permissions to the CERT related files (.crt/ .key/ .csr). After that, more badly, one of the file was wrong.

Comment: Your answer helped me figure out an SSL related problem causing the SELinux error above.

In my case I was missing `SSLEngine on` in my vhost conf

Interestingly `service httpd configtest` did not show any errors

Answer (score 3):

```
Apache Error [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

One fine morning I have discovered that my Apache (httpd) service is down and can't be started :)

Step 1: Checking httpd Service Status:

```
#/etc/init.d/httpd status
```

httpd dead but pid file exists

Step 2: Search httpd processes and kill those

```
#ps -ef | grep httpd

# killall -9 httpd
```

Step 3: Remove httpd lock file if exist

```
# rm -f /var/lock/subsys/httpd
```

Step4: Restart Apache/httpd Service

```
# service httpd restart
Stop httpd    [FAILED]
Start httpd   [FAILED]
```

Need to dig down more.

Step 5: Check httpd error log file

```
# grep suexec /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Sun Sep 22 10:32:06 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Sep 22 10:33:51 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Sep 22 10:38:03 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Sep 22 10:45:53 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

Step 6: Check httpd nss error log file

```
#tail -300 /var/log/httpd/nss_error_log
[Sun Sep 22 04:03:27 2013] [error] Certificate not verified: 'Server-Cert'
[Sun Sep 22 04:03:27 2013] [error] SSL Library Error: -8181 Certificate has expired
[Sun Sep 22 04:03:27 2013] [error] Unable to verify certificate 'Server-Cert'. Add "NSSEnforceValidCerts off" to nss.conf so the server can start until the problem can be resolved.

[Sun Sep 22 10:38:03 2013] [error] Certificate not verified: 'Server-Cert'
[Sun Sep 22 10:38:03 2013] [error] SSL Library Error: -8181 Certificate has expired
[Sun Sep 22 10:38:03 2013] [error] Unable to verify certificate 'Server-Cert'. Add "NSSEnforceValidCerts off" to nss.conf so the server can start until the problem can be resolved.
[Sun Sep 22 10:45:53 2013] [error] Certificate not verified: 'Server-Cert'
[Sun Sep 22 10:45:53 2013] [error] SSL Library Error: -8181 Certificate has expired
[Sun Sep 22 10:45:53 2013] [error] Unable to verify certificate 'Server-Cert'. Add "NSSEnforceValidCerts off" to nss.conf so the server can start until the problem can be resolved.
```

root cause of this issue is in a module called nss. `mod_nss` is an alternative to `mod_ssl`; it does a few things that `mod_ssl` doesn't do, and can run along side `mod_ssl`. For more information's, please go through the links [What is mod_nss , On Setting up Mod_NSS ,More detail ]

Step 7: Remove nss.conf file from httpd conf.d directory

```
#cd /etc/httpd/conf.d
#mv nss.conf nss.conf.orig
#mv ssl.conf ssl.conf.orig
#/etc/init.d/httpd start
Start httpd   [OK]
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Don't forget to read the [help page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected that by re-installing the mod_ssl in CentOS 6 with `yum erase mod_ssl` and installing it with `yum mod_ssl`. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This one fixed my issue.

```
yumpurge () 
{ 
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "usage:
            removes packages including config files
            example:
            $0 ['pkg1 pkg2 pkgn']
            ";
        return 0;
    fi;
    for package in "$*";
    do
        echo "removing config files for $package";
        for file in $(rpm -q --configfiles $package);
        do
            echo "removing $file";
            echo "enter any key to confirm";
            rm -i -f $file;
        done;
        rpm -e $package;
    done
}


yumpurge  mod_ssl   httpd
yum install -y httpd mod_ssl
```